# Setting My App's Theme

Tags: android, colors, themes, android-actionbar

In my styles.xml file in the values-v14 folder (my app is API 16+, so I'm not too worried about the values-v11 and values folder), I have this line:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

In my class, I have these lines:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
actionBar.setTitle("TEXT");
```

Unfortunately, the result of this is that I have a line of text that's white in color on a white background (pretty much becoming invisible). I am aiming for black text on a white background. I tried using `setTitleColor(Color.BLACK);` but that doesn't change the text color.

I've also tried writing `parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.LightActionBar"` but that doesn't seem to exist. I've tried writing `parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.ActionBar"` but that doesn't seem to exist. I've tried writing `parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"` but, while that exists, it doesn't change the text color.

So what's the right combination that I should be using here?

On another note, I have an overflow menu icon (the 3 little vertical squares) that's also exhibiting the same problem, it's white and I want it to be the typical gray that one normally sees on a light background.

**Edit:**

```
<resources>
    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
            <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: `Theme.Holo.Light` doesn't work for you? The text on it should be dark already

Comment: Right. When I set it to `Theme.Holo.Light`, the text is still white.

Comment: Maybe show us the rest of your styles.xml, something else might be causing it.

Comment: All right. I've updated with the code from my styles.xml file.

Comment: That's weird. I used Theme.Holo.Light and added `getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));` in onCreate() and it works fine...

Comment: Yes. I understand. That actually works for me too. When I set the background to white, it works, the problem is that I want to set the foreground (text) to black because currently the text is white too.

Comment: No, I mean I got the white action bar and had dark text too.